# Web service running batch mode file level operations

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

We have a three tier architecture,

1. Database
2. Web service -- which kind of acts like a wrapper to the database and controls the work flow
3. Windows service -- which does the actual work involving lots of file level operation like splitting a file, compressing, transferring it to an FTP site, etc

We have some inefficiencies with our DB structure and are now planning to refactor that, during the design meeting one of the questions that came up was

1. Why do we need to have a separate windows service, can't we make the web service decide the logic and do the actual work (i.e., including the windows service work)

one obvious answer was that it would be difficult to scale if we have the web service running the actual work (file level operations) as it would be able to use the resources from only that machine

But apart from this is there any specific reason why not to use web services for performing batch-mode file level operations.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Is the Web service layer by any chance a WCF service that is wrapping a Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) workflow?

Comment: Yes, It is a WCF service but we are not using WF

Comment: How is the windows service notified that something needs to be done?  Alternatively, does the windows service wake up at regular intervals and look for something to do?

Comment: Yep thats what happens, the windows service wakes up every 5 minutes and asks the web service for something to do

Comment: A web service is supposed to *enable* communication between two endpoints, not *initiate* communication, so it doesn't seem like a good fit to me.  You'd need to add a long-running thread to your web service to make it wake up every 5 minutes.  Review this link for a discussion of this topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/e34699dd-3b48-43e6-ac7d-2c5fd088c8bb/how-to-spin-a-worker-threads-on-startup-of-the-wcf-server?forum=wcf